# How can I make this hover code shorter? And how can I create a css file that implements settings to more than one button?

Tags: php, css, hover

Someone made this piece of code for me and I think there's some unnecessary bits in it.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" 
/> <title>IS THIS THING ON?</title> <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="./wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css" 
type="text/css" />
</style>
</head> <body>
<a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" class="myButton"><!-- 
button --></a>
</body> </html>
```

And this is the CSS file it refers too:

```
   .myButton {
    background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif) no-repeat;
    border: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    } .myButton:hover {
    background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/too.gif) no-repeat;
    }
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Can the first piece of code shortened?
2. How can I create a CSS file that implements settings to more than one of these settings. Just like this one does in my CSS file to links:

> ```
> #userbar #bp-nav li.current a{
>    color:#000;
>    font-weight:bold;
> }
>    #userbar #bp-nav li a:hover {
>    color: #3193c7; text-decoration: none; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

> **1** Can the first piece of code shortened?

If you are so concerned about the size than remove the `<!-- button -->` html comment.

```
./wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css
```

is equivelent to:

```
wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css
```

Saving 2 characters :)

As it seems to me in the CSS file you can shorten the path to the images. Instead:

```
background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif) no-repeat;
...
background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/too.gif) no-repeat;
```

use relative URLs:

```
background: url(../images/see.gif) no-repeat;
...
background: url(../images/too.gif) no-repeat;
```

> **2** How can I create a CSS file that implements settings to more than one of these settings. Just like this one does in my CSS file to links:

If you don't want to add the CSS class to every element you have to wrap them in some other element

```
...
</head> <body>
<div class="buttons">
<a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" ></a>
<div class="buttons"><a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" ></a>
<div class="buttons"><a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" ></a>
<div class="buttons"><a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" ></a>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

And the CSS

```
.buttons a {
    background: url(../images/see.gif) no-repeat;
    border: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
} 
.buttons a:hover {
    background: url(../images/too.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

The `cursor` is usually used if the `href` attribute is not set.

Answer (score 1):

The css is almost as short as it gets.

Since this is being applied to an `a`, you could remove `cursor: pointer;`.

Also, if you are using a `background-image`, you might not need `border: 1;`.

The other styles look necessary to render the button, that is `height` and `width` and `display`.

You can also smush it together like your other example:

```
.myButton {background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif) no-repeat; display: block; height: 22px; width: 22px; margin-left: 5px;} 
.myButton:hover {background: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/too.gif) no-repeat;}
```

As for reusing these styles, you can do 1 of 2 things:

1. add `.myButton` to other `a` elements or
2. add more classes to the rule, e.g., `.myButton, .otherClass {//css in here}` referencing the `.otherClass` in another `a`

Answer (score 1):

The first piece 'of code' is a full html page. If you only need to add the button on a page, this part will do:

```
<a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" class="myButton"><!--button--></a>
```

The part between  is a comment, that could theoretically still go a well. Remember to add the CSS information to that page's CSS file though!

--

If you'd want more links to show up as a button, you could add the class="myButton" to the A-tag you want changed. If you want multiple classes to change into a button you can add them to the CSS, just as with the other example you've given:

```
.myButton .myOtherButton { ... }
.myButton:hover .myOtherButton:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:
Make a single image with both button states(a sprite), then:

```
.myButton {
background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif);
display: block;
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
} 
.myButton:hover {
background-position: x y;
}
```

This will also solve the flickring issue when one hovers the link.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: .myButton {
background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif);
display: block;
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
} 
.myButton:hover {
background-position: x y;
}

Comment: I tried to make a sprite by copy-pasting the code you gave to the userbar.php file. I kept the CSS the same as above. I saved the file with photoshop "save for web -> gif 64 no dither" and kept a small space between the two images in the file. I then uploaded it and referred to the file. But for some reason it only shows the normal image without the hover. Any ideas what I did wrong there? 

The code for php:

Comment: I tried to make a sprite by copy-pasting the code you gave to the userbar.php file. I kept the CSS the same as above. I saved the file with photoshop "save for web -> gif 64 no dither" and kept a small space between the two images in the file. I then uploaded it and referred to the file. But for some reason it only shows the normal image without the hover. Any ideas what I did wrong there? The code for php:
.myButton {
background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif);
display: block;
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
} 
.myButton:hover {
background-position: x y;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 and omit some optional elements, attributes and closing slashes [*á la* Anne van Kesteren](http://annevankesteren.nl/), which would leave you with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>IS THIS THING ON?</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css">
<a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" class="myButton"></a>
```

As for the CSS, I can add little to antitoxic and gutierrezalex's comments about using relative URLs and CSS sprites, save that you could also run the final code through a minifier. ([Robson's CSS compressor](http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/code/css_compressor.php) can shave off a few bytes by removing things like whitespace and the final semicolon in a property block.)