# Hover image shows only original image without hover image when trying to create a sprite. Any ideas?

Tags: php, css, hover, sprite

I tried to make a sprite by copy-pasting the code you gave to the userbar.php file. I kept the CSS the same as above. I saved the file with photoshop "save for web -> gif 64 no dither" and kept a small space between the two images in the file. I then uploaded it and referred to the file. But for some reason it only shows the normal image without the hover. Any ideas what I did wrong there? The code for php:

```
.myButton {
background-image: url(/wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/see.gif);
display: block;
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
} 
.myButton:hover {
background-position: x y;
}
```

The original thread: [How can I make this hover code shorter? And how can I create a css file that implements settings to more than one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819962/how-can-i-make-this-hover-code-shorter-and-how-can-i-create-a-css-file-that-impl)

Comment: What dimensions do your sprite has? 22x44, 44x22?

Comment: there are no _x_ and _y_ in css

Comment: Just an FYI, this isn't PHP, it's just CSS.  Even though you may be including it in a PHP file, it's still CSS and has nothing to do with PHP.  Just wanted to let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.myButton:hover {
    background-position-x: -22px;
}
```

if the sprite is horizontal, else `background-position-y`.

For better understanding of sprites, watch [this article about spites on nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/exactly-how-to-use-css-sprites/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.myButton:hover {
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to specify the actual positional values for the sprites located in see.gif, as it's not clear if you're using `x y` as values or just as a placeholder for the snippet above.

If it's not a placeholder, well yeah - there's your problem. Just change x into the actual x-position and y into the y-position and you'll be fine.