# Applying css class to more than one element. It applied to all of them. How can I specify?

Tags: css, hover

I followed the instructions as posted in the first answer of this thread:

[How can I make this hover code shorter? And how can I create a css file that implements settings to more than one button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819962/how-can-i-make-this-hover-code-shorter-and-how-can-i-create-a-css-file-that-impl)

But the button was added to all the links. All I want to do is create more buttons while keeping the code short so that one piece of css settings could be applied to other similar buttons. Please help? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? What about using a class name? Are you able to select the elements through ancestory? (is the ancestory known?)

Comment: I tried to use parts of the old code snipped I had, but nothing good came out of that. I'm quite new at this so using a class name is something I haven't done yet. I'll look into that. Also, I'll check what the ancestory is all about. Letting you explain it here would be too much to ask I think, yes?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access elements in your CSS witout affecting *all* elements of that type on the page there are a couple of things you can do.

Firstly I'd advise you to look into the [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to learn more about the different ways you can select elements.

Here's a couple of the top of my head that may be useful to you.

**Selecting by ID or Class**

You can select a single element by its ID or multiple items by their class name. Bare in mind that only one element on a page may have the same ID but many elements can have the same class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myIdSelector"></div>
```

and

```
<div class="myClassSelector"></div>
```

**CSS**

ID's are referenced using the `#` symbol and classes using the `.` (period) symbol in CSS

```
    #myIdSelector{
     /* Styles for this single item */
    }

    .myyClassSelector{
    /* Styles here for this collection of items */
   }
```

**Decendent selection**

This basically refers to selecting an element based on it being a decendent in some way to another element. The simplest form of this is the child selector. Consider the following:

```
div p{ /* styles here */}
```

This is referencing all paragraph tags that are inside of (children of) a div.

Another example combining the ID selector with the child selector:

```
#myNavMenu li a{ /* styles here */}
```

This time we're styling all anchor elements that are inside list elements, which in turn are inside something with an ID of `myNavMenu`.