# How do I make images appear side by side?

Tags: php, css, image

I googled it, but didn't find a satisfactory answer. Do I change the CSS file or the PHP file?

Secondly, is there a better way of getting more than one image to appear on a page than copy-pasting the php code like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
 <head> 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
     <title>IS THIS THING ON?</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css" type="text/css" />
 </head> 
 <body>
    <a href="<?php bp_send_public_message_link() ?>" class="myButton"><!-- button --></a>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

While this is the CSS code:

```
.myButton {
background-image: url(/wp-content     /themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/kaksnuppu.gif);
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
margin-left: 5px;
display:inline;
} 

.myButton:hover {
background-position: 0px 25px;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean to have two complete web pages in a single file?  Hopefully not.

Comment: Learn to walk before you try to run. Start with getting an understanding of HTML, before you move on to CSS and then PHP.

Comment: in context of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819962/how-can-i-make-this-hover-code-shorter-and-how-can-i-create-a-css-file-that-impl

Comment: @Scott I'm using wordpress' buddypress to build a social media website.

Comment: @RedFilter, I have read about it and I admit all of this is quite new and big to me, but I think it's a good way to learn. I do google before I come here with questions.

Answer (score 1):

First off you only need to declare the page once:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" 
/> <title>IS THIS THING ON?</title> <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="./wp-content/themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/css/screen.css" 
type="text/css" />
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Content goes here --> 
</body>
</html>`

Any content should be in between the body tag.

Second, you can display images using this code:

`<img src="dir/image.jpg" width="x" height="x" alt="Alt Title">`

You can repeat this code as many times as you want inside the `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your CSS you're declaring the element to be BOTH block and inline.. one is overriding the other

I would suggest changing your CSS to be inline-block .

(see the edited code)

Also see the suggestions from @David Nguyen

```
.myButton {
    background-image: url(/wp-content     /themes/cosmicbuddy/_inc/images/kaksnuppu.gif);
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline` won't trigger width an height - also the background image won't show as intended.

Comment: Use either `display:block` or `display:inline-block` if you want sizing properties to work.

Comment: I tried both:
    display:inline-block;
    display:inline;
but they're still underneath each other for some reason.

Comment: @Easwee I tried both: display:inline-block; display:inline; but they're still underneath each other for some reason.